# pandas - percentage of matr

Tags: python, pandas

Afternoon,

I am trying to recreate a table but replacing the raw numbers with percentage of the total column. For instance, i have:

```
Code    03/31/2016    12/31/2015   09/30/2015
F55     425           387          369
F554    109           106          106
F508    105           105          106
```

the desired output is a new dataframe, with the numbers replaced by the percentage with the total being the sum of the column (03/31/2016 = 425+109+105)

```
Code    03/31/2016    12/31/2015   09/30/2015
F55     66.5%         64.7%          63.5%
F554    17%           17.7%          18.2%
F508    16.4%         17.5%          18.2%
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more elegant answer somewhere but this will work:

```
df['03/31/2016'].apply(lambda x : x/df['03/31/2016'].sum())
```

or if you want to do this for the entire dataframe:

```
df.apply(lambda x : x/x.sum(), axis=0)
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way of not specifying the column heading as this changes through time

Comment: In your post, you didn't do this for the 3rd column, so if that's the desired behavior, you'll need to pass in a column heading either way.  If that was just a typo, I've updated my answer with an example on how you would do this operation for the entire dataframe.